# template not found in grails application

Tags: grails, tags, gsp

I just upgraded to grails 2.2.4 from 2.1.2. Everything works fine on my local but, however, when I packaged the WAR onto the test environment I am seeing a weird error. On a form that uses a template I am getting an error:

> template not found for name [form] and path [/base/_form.gsp].

However, this template (using from create.gsp) is not under the base folder. It is under a folder called color (under views), which is where both `create.gsp` and `_form.gsp` reside

This is the tag I'm using from create.gsp:

```
<g:render template="form" bean="${mybean}"/>
```

It seems that grails is assume that the template lives in `base` but it really lives in `color`.

Comment: You are sure you don't have that tag in a view under /base ?

Comment: No, I don't have it under /base

Comment: I don't even have a folder called /base under views

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error,

```
template not found for name [form] and path [/base/_form.gsp]
```

because Grails is looking for `_form.gsp` in a path relative by convention to a folder with the same name as the controller that is rendering the parent gsp. This will always be the case if you don't supply an absolute path (starting from `views` folder) in the render tag.

Where is your _form.gsp page? Here are some example paths

```
grails-app/views/_form.gsp           
    -> <g:render template="/form" ..

grails-app/views/base/_form.gsp      
    -> <g:render template="/base/form" ... 
 or -> <g:render template="form" ..  //if calling from baseController
```

So if _form.gsp lives in color and color is at grails-app/views/color, you would need the following path in your render tag:

```
<g:render template="/color/form"
```

Comment: This seems to solve it but why is this happening? It doesn't cause any problems on my local environment. Now all of a sudden I have to make changes like these all across my application. for example: I even have to change `<g:form action="save"...` to `<g:form action="/color/save`

Comment: Grails defaults are usually [based on convention](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#conventionOverConfiguration) .For example SomeController will have corresponding gsp in /views/some/, and any action in the gsp will be relative to /views/some and submit to SomeController unless you explicitly define something else. So in your g:form, you should specify `controller` attribute in addition to `action`.

Comment: it looks like you may have move some gsp files around or rename some domain/controllers at some point if it was working at an early time. If that's the case then you may have a lot of broken links

Comment: I am using the default convention. I have a ColorController which has a save action. In /views/color I have a create.gsp which has a form tag <g:form action="save". Which should go to ColorController's save action. Additionally, if it works ok in dev it should work ok in grails test run-war as well. I am trying your solution now though..